# What is the minimum and maximum value taken by scale Factor while Zooming in android?

Tags: java, android, zooming, scale

I am using the below function to get the scale factor.

I see values are > 1 when Zooming in
and < 1 when Zooming out.

What is the exact meaning of these? And majorly,
what is the minimum and maximum value taken by scale Factor while Zooming in & Zooming out?

```
public class MyScaleGestureListener implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector) {
            Log.i(TAG,"zoom value : " + scaleGestureDetector.getScaleFactor());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or is there any way by which I can make sure the scale factor is between 0 & 1?

Comment: If I remember well, the default bounds are [0.6, 8] but it can be overrided by the application

Comment: Zoom range between 0 to 1 valuers